# borders in java

Tags: java, swing

I want to set single title border to group of textfields how can i do this in java / swing.

i have tried below code but text fields are compressing inside panel

```
// Create panel and add some components to it.
JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

pnl.add(new JLabel("Name"));
pnl.add(new JTextField());

// Add titled border to panel, which will therefore surround
// all child components placed on the panel.
pnl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("It's Friday!"));
```

Comment: Can you provide more context? Is this a swing application? AWT? HTML?

Comment: Please explain this "text fields are compressing inside panel" statement! What are you seeing and what would you rather see happening?

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example using Swing:

```
// Create panel and add some components to it.
JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

pnl.add(new JLabel("Name"));
pnl.add(new JTextField());

// Add titled border to panel, which will therefore surround
// all child components placed on the panel.
pnl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("It's Friday!"));
```

Comment: i have tried this but text fields are compressing inside panel

Comment: The text fields "compressing" is not a result of applying the border, but rather because you haven't set a preferred size.  For `JTextField` you can do this using `setPreferredSize` or create the text field with a specified number of columns.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the text fields have no size set yet.
It's quickest to set a size by using the [setColumns(int)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#setColumns(int)) method. You could also use the setPreferredSize(Dimension).